# Relation between tables

Tags: foreign-key, relational-theory

**This question may be too easy to ask, but I can't understand how to do it.**

I am new in SQL.

I have two tables.

> Table I
>
> book_id (AI & Primary Key)
>
> book_name
>
> book_year

Table II

> writer_id (AI & Primary Key)
>
> writer_name
>
> writer_bio

I want to create a relation between book_id and writer_id. When I add a new book, I don't want to store the writer's name for the every single time, I want to connect it to a specific writer_id. That's how relational databases work, right?

A writer could be written more than one book, but a book also can be written by more than one writers. How can I make the relation?

I also appreciate any kind of link to understand how this works.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that in a case like this you need a linking table that will allow for that many to many relationship.  Something like

```
Create Table tblBookWriter
(tblBookWriter_ID int
, Book_id --(FK to Book table-Book_Id)
, Writer_id --(FK to Writer table-Writer_Id)
);
```

With this you can add have a book with as many writers as it needs and a writer can have authored as many books as is needed.  Something like that should get it for you anyway.

If you do a web search for "database many to many linking table" you will see all kinds of results.  The first is a wiki link for a [Junction Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't need to use foreign keys if I apply this solution, do I?

Comment: Absolutely.  There should be foreign key links to both the book_id and the writer_id.  I modified my answer to include reference to that.